# convert json to another structure

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am trying to convert the structure by having a list with different category and type and combine them to a diff structure (group by type name).

I have put the full structure inside the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ymrgo5/1)

The plan is to understand how to do it using javascript or c#.

```
var fromJson = [
{
    "type" : "Chicken",
  "total" : 1,
  "category" : "healthy"
},
{
    "type" : "Pig",
  "total" : 10,
  "category" : "healthy"
},
{
    "type" : "Pig",
  "total" : 5,
  "category" : "unhealthy"
},
{
    "type" : "Cow",
  "total" : 15,
  "category" : "healthy"
}
];
```

To

```
var final_out = [
    {
    "type" : "chicken",
    "healthy" : 1,
    "unhealthy" : 0
  },
  {
    "type" : "Pig",
    "healthy" : 10,
    "unhealthy" : 5
  },
  {
    "type" : "Cow",
    "healthy" : 15,
    "unhealthy" : 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your effort

Comment: Final out is not proper JSON.

Comment: Tried using c# but ienumerables is immutable.

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=38b12c5e9552bc41b600c33493645d87

Comment: How open are you to use `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: actually this is a web api 2 project. if i can convert it to arraylist, ienumerable or json is still fine. i just want to know the algorithm on how to solve it.

Comment: "Tried using c# but ienumerables is immutable". I have no idea how you stumbled across mutability from attempting to deserialize Json, but share code which you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class RootObject
{
  List<RootType> rootType;
}    

public class RootType
{
  public int healthy { get; set; }
  public int unhealthy { get; set; }
}
```

or just:

```
public class RootObject
{
  public string type { get; set; }
  public int healthy { get; set; }
  public int unhealthy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already have this poco. The problem is to iterate and push in the collection. but during the checking, if the type already exists, I somehow need to modify the collection but during foreach loop i can't change any element inside.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of modifying the collection, Try removing the actual object and add it back again with updated data. I use `Linq` for this.

Below is a small function that i put together to do this.

```
public string ReturnFinalOutput(string InputJson)
{
    List<fromJson> input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fromJson>>(InputJson);
    List<final_out> output = new List<final_out>();
    foreach (fromJson j in input)
    {
        final_out o = new final_out();
        var finalout = output.FirstOrDefault<final_out>(a => a.type == j.type);
        if (finalout == null)
        {
            o.type = j.type;
            if (j.category == "healthy")
            {
                o.healthy = o.healthy + 1;
            }
            else if (j.category == "unhealthy")
            {
                o.unhealthy = o.unhealthy + 1;
            }
            output.Add(o);
        }
        else
        {
            output.Remove(finalout);
            if (j.category == "healthy")
            {
                finalout.healthy = finalout.healthy + 1;
            }
            else if (j.category == "unhealthy")
            {
                finalout.unhealthy = finalout.unhealthy + 1;
            }
            output.Add(finalout);
        }
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
}
```

and Below are my `BaseClasses`

```
public class fromJson
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class final_out
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int healthy { get; set; } = 0;
    public int unhealthy { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

you can call this as

```
string final_out = ReturnFinalOutput(fromJson); // fromJson is your InputJson.
```